# How can I form a SQL Query for a HSQLDB that counts the # of rows per day using a BIGINT type for a date?

Tags: sql, date, group-by, hsqldb, bigint

I have an HSQLDB, ver. 1.8.0, database with a sample schema with something like this:

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE ENTRY
(ENTRYID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 REQID VARCHAR,
 REVOCATIONDATE BIGINT)
```

I would like to retrieve a row count for every date, something like this:

```
ENTRYID  DATE_COUNT REVOCATIONDATE  

1           10       2014-01-01  
2           5        2014-01-02  
3           15       2014-01-03
```

The problem is that the REVOCATIONDATE is a BIGINT instead of a normal date or timestamp.  This is a vendor provided DB so, assume the schema is not allowed to be changed.

How can I create a SQL query that will do this?

Comment: You're going to need a function that accepts the BIGINT value and returns an actual date.  Without further information, I have no idea what the code for that function might look like.

Comment: I looked at the 1.8 user guide on SQL and didn't see anything relating to BIGINT dates.   
http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html

Comment: That's probably because the vendor created their own custom implementation of the date.  You need to find out from them how the date is formulated in the BIGINT, so that you can write a conversion function.

Comment: The vendor used Java to convert on the client-side.  I would like a native SQL command to do it so that I can do it from the HSQL Tool.

Comment: Some inline math might be possible, if you examine the Java to understand the algorithm.

Comment: This would be quite easy with a current version of HSQLDB (2.3) but I don't think this is possible without writing your own function for HSQLDB 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is HSQLDB 1.8 is an old version and does not support some advanced functions. HSQLDB 2.3.x supports a full range of functions to convert between different representations.

With HSQLDB 1.8 it is possible to create your own function in Java to convert the millisecond value of a Timestamp to a java.sql.Timestamp or java.sql.Date

Something like this in a class that you create:

```
static java.sql.Date millisToDate(long millis) {
    return new java.sql.Date(millis);
}
```

If you then include this class on the classpath used for running the database, you can call the function in your SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT ENTRYID, "myclass.millisToDate"(REVOCATIONDATE) FROM ENTRY
```

Your result example will look like this:

```
SELECT MIN(ENTRYID), COUNT(ENTRYID), "myclass.millisToDate"(REVOCATIONDATE) FROM ENTRY
    GROUP BY "myclass.millisToDate"(REVOCATIONDATE)
```

I haven't actually tried any of the above suggestions, but they should work, perhaps with some alteration.